# Remove percentages from robocopy log

Tags: powershell, robocopy

I'm using an older version of `robocopy` that includes percentages in the log even if the `/NJH` and `/NJS` paramters are set. So I'd like to remove the percentages from the log:

```
            72880735    H:\1.txt
100%  
            33038490    H:\10.txt
100%  
            64878348    H:\2.txt
100%  
            25875810    H:\3.txt
  0%  
100%
```

I've tried with

```
(Get-Content $logfile) | Where-Object {
    $_ -match '[\s](\d{1,})(\s+)(\w\W\W.+)'
} | Set-Content $logfile
```

But that results in

```
            72880735    H:\1.txt
            33038490    H:\10.txt 
            64878348    H:\2.txt
            25875810    H:\3.txt
  0%
```

So I get the 100%'s stripped out, but not the 0%.

Comment: Try `Where{$_ -match '[\s](\d{1,})(\s+)(\w\W\W.+)' -and $_ -notlike '*%*'}` Edit: I looked again and that doesn't make sense. You should not get `0%` with that regex. I even tested it on [RegEx101](https://regex101.com/r/gvLGw7/1).

Comment: @TheMadTechnician - Some day, robocopy will understand a PS-Drive name longer than one letter. Will the regex work then?

Comment: That worked @TheMadTechnician!

Answer (score 15, accepted):

`/njh` and `/njs` have nothing to do with the percentage information. You need to suppress progress output by adding the option `/np` to your `robocopy` commandline.

From the [documentation](https://technet.microsoft.com/de-de/library/cc733145.aspx):

> `/np` Specifies that the progress of the copying operation (the number of files or directories copied so far) will not be displayed.

---

**Edit:** After taking a look at your actual commandline it looks like `/np` is not compatible with `/mt`. Adding the latter parameter makes `robocopy` display progress output even if `/np` is present. If you don't require running multi-threaded I'd remove that parameter (add `/ndl` to prevent directories from appearing in the output).

I would also recommend using [splatting](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/reference/3.0/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_splatting) instead of putting the parameter list into a single string:

```
$params = $src, $dest, ('/LOG:"{0}"' -f $logpath), '/L', '/NP', '/NC', '/BYTES',
          '/NJH', '/NJS', '/NDL', '/E', '/MOVE', '/XC', '/XN', '/XO', '/XD',
          $excludedFoldersList

& robocopy @params
```

---

If for some reason you must use multi-threading you should be able to remove progress information from the log after completion like this:

```
(Get-Content $logpath) | Where-Object {
    $_ -notmatch '^\s*\d{1,3}%\s*$'
} | Set-Content $logpath
```

Comment: I should have mentioned that, but the /NP paramter is also set. I mentioned `/njh` and `/njs` as I saw it mentioned in another post that setting these would suppress the percentages.

Comment: @Moller If that parameter were set you wouldn't be getting progress output in your log. I'm not making this up. Please show your full `robocopy` commandline and tell us the (file) version number of the executable.

Comment: I don't think you are, not at all. I'm pretty new to powershell so I'm sure I messed up somewhere. 
It's the Win 8.1 `robocopy` version from 2014, `ProductVersion:   6.3.9600.16384`

Comment: That version should behave exactly as I described. Please show your full commandline.

Comment: `'"{0} " "{1} " /LOG:"{2}" /L /NP /NC /BYTES /NJH /NJS /MT /E /MOVE /XD {3} /XC /XN /XO' -f $src, $dest, $logPath, [string]::Join(' ', $excludedFoldersList)`

So i use it with some variables and execute it with `Start-Process`.